# MiniZinc: type error: expected `array[int] of int', actual `array[int] of var opt int

Tags: minizinc

I am trying to write a predicate that performs the same operation as `circuit`, but ignores zeros in the array, and I keep getting the following error:

`MiniZinc: type error: initialisation value for 'x_without_0' has invalid type-inst: expected 'array[int] of int', actual 'array[int] of var opt int'`

in the code:

```
% [0,5,2,0,7,0,3,0] -> true
% [0,5,2,0,4,0,3,0] -> false (no circuit)
% [0,5,2,0,3,0,8,7] -> false (two circuits)
predicate circuit_ignoring_0(array[int] of var int: x) =
  let { 
        array[int] of int: x_without_0 = [x[i] | i in 1..length(x) where x[i] != 0],
        int: lbx = min(x_without_0),
        int: ubx = max(x_without_0),
        int: len = length(x_without_0),
        array[1..len] of var lbx..ubx: order
  } in
  alldifferent(x_without_0) /\
  alldifferent(order) /\

  order[1] = x_without_0[1] /\ 
  forall(i in 2..len) (
     order[i] = x_without_0[order[i-1]]
  )
  /\  % last value is the minimum (symmetry breaking)
  order[ubx] = lbx
;
```

I am using MiniZinc v2.0.11

**Edit**

Per Kobbe's suggestion that it was an issue with having a variable length array, I used ["the usual workaround"](https://www.minizinc.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=81&p=244&hilit=maria#p245) of keeping the `order` array the same size as the original array `x`, and using a parameter, `nnonzeros`, to keep track of the part of the array I care about:

```
set of int: S = index_set(x),
int: u = max(S),
var int: nnonzeros = among(x, S),
array[S] of var 0..u: order
```

Comment: The error tells that x_without_0 is an array of var int, and you defined it as an array of int which is why it fails. Maybe you also want to define lbx and ubx also as var ints?

Comment: @Emilien Nice idea, but unfortunately when I change the type of x_without_0 to `array[int] of var int`, and lbx/ubx to `var int`, the error just changes to `expected 'array[int] of var int', actual 'array[int] of var opt int'`.

Comment: Yes, in fact the formula that defines x_without_0 makes it an array of optional var integers. I'm not very aware of this [new feature](http://www.minizinc.org/2.0/doc-lib/doc-optiontypes.html) ([publication](http://people.eng.unimelb.edu.au/pstuckey/papers/mznopt.pdf))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of answers your question:

The problem you are experiencing is that your array size is dependent on a `var`. This means that MiniZinc can not really know the size of the array is should create and the `opt` type is used. I would suggest that you stay away from the `opt` type if you do not know how to handle it.

Generally the solution is to make some workaround where your arrays are not dependent of the size of an `var`. My solution is most often to pad the array, i.e `[2,0,5,0,8] -> [2,2,5,5,8]`, if the application allows it, or

```
var int : a;
[i * bool2int(i == a) in 1..5]
```

if you are okay with zeroes in your answer (I guess not in this case).

Furthermore, the `alldifferent_except_0` could be in interest for you, or at least you can look how `alldifferent_except_0` solves the problem with zeroes in the answer.

```
predicate alldifferent_except_0(array [int] of var int: vs) =
forall ( i, j in index_set(vs) where i < j ) ( 
    vs[i]!=0 /\ vs[j]!=0 -> vs[i]!=vs[j] 
)
```

from [MiniZinc documentation](http://www.minizinc.org/2.0/doc-lib/doc-globals-alldifferent.html)

Comment: Yup, that was it!  Makes sense, actually, that MiniZinc wouldn't allow array size to be determined at runtime.  Gonna mark this as the accepted answer.