# Cardinality constraint type failure; how to use minizinc `card` correctly

Tags: minizinc

The following model works for langfords problem

```
int: m = 2;
int: n = 3;

set of int: DOM = 1..m*n;
set of int: RAN = 1..n;

array [DOM] of var 1..n: nos;

constraint forall(j in DOM, k in j+1..m*n) (nos[j] = nos[k] /\ forall(l in j + 1 .. k - 1)(nos[l] != nos[k]) -> k - j = nos[j] + 1);

constraint forall(r in RAN)( sum([1 | i in DOM where nos[i] = r]) = m);

solve satisfy;
```

However the to more more natural reading constraint

```
constraint forall(r in RAN)( card({i | i in DOM where nos[i] = r}) = m);
```

fails with the error

```
MiniZinc: type error: no function or predicate with this signature found: `card(var opt set of int)'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your set size is dependent on a `var`, this means that the type is `var opt` insted of `var` as you would imagine.

For more information read here:

[MiniZinc: type error: expected `array[int] of int', actual `array[int] of var opt int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35462086/minizinc-type-error-expected-arrayint-of-int-actual-arrayint-of-var-op)